# How to set and verify file's origin?

Tags: cryptography

Can you guys suggest any method for my below problem?

I am developing an application which requires users to download an excel file, modify some content and upload exactly the same file they just download.

The requirement started from the fact that there is macro inside the excel file (which can be changed often), hence I try to make sure they always download and do works with the latest version. Then have to upload that file again.

My system is a web-based application for your reference.

Comment: If the file is changed ("modify some content") then it can not be "exactly the same file".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is not a programming question. You need a version control system